# If $Y$ is an open subspace of $X$ then the boundary in $Y$ of an open set $A$ of $Y$ is the intersection of the boundary of $A$ in $X$ and $Y$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Statement**

If $Y$ is an open subspace of $X$ then the boundary $\partial_Y$ in $Y$  of an open set $A$ of $Y$ is the intersection of the boundary $\partial_X$ of $A$ in $X$ and $Y$, that is
$$
\partial_Y A=\partial_X A\cap Y
$$

*Proof*. So if $x\in\partial_Y A$ then $x\in Y$ and for any open set $U$ of $X$ containing $x$ it must be $(U\cap Y)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $(U\cap Y)\cap(Y\setminus A)\neq\emptyset$ but $(U\cap Y)\subseteq U$ and $Y\setminus A\subseteq X\setminus A$ so that $x\in\partial_X A$ and thus $\partial_Y A\subseteq(\partial_X A\cap Y)$. Conversely if $x\in(\partial_X A\cap Y)$ then $x\in Y$ and if $U\cap Y\setminus A=\emptyset$ for some neighborhood of $x$ then $\overset{\circ}{\overbrace{U\cap Y}}=(U\cap Y)\subseteq A$ and thus $x\in\overset{\,\,\circ}A=A$ that would implies $\partial_X A\cap A\neq\emptyset$ that is not possible.

So is the statement true and in that case are my arguments correct?

Comment: This is not a common notation, you should explain what is $\partial _XA$.

Comment: Simply the symbol $\partial$ indicate the boundary of a set and so $\partial_Y$ indicate the boundary of a set in the subspace $Y$, that's all.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I think you lost the requirement that $A$ be open in $Y$ while editing

Comment: @hgmath Oh yeah!!! Just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me.

Alternatively, it might be a bit easier to use that $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus A$ for open sets $A$.

Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$ in $X$. Then $\overline{A}\cap Y$ is the closure of $A$ in $Y$, hence
$$ \partial_Y A = (\overline{A}\cap Y)\setminus A = (\overline{A}\setminus A)\cap Y = \partial_X A \cap Y$$

Comment: Oh, amazing! Thansk to much for your assistance!